# Function is executing regardless of alert prompt button response?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so I have this archive function which I want to happen only when the user selects "YES" button on the alert prompt that comes up, however it seems to be executing regardless of the input (before they input anything). How can I fix this?

```
function cloneGooglesheet() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var cellfirst = ss.getSheetByName('Master').getRange(4, 1).getValue();
      var celllast = ss.getSheetByName('Master').getRange(10, 1).getValue();
      var startdate = Utilities.formatDate(cellfirst, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");
      var enddate = Utilities.formatDate(celllast, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");
      var sheetName = "Week of '"+startdate+"' to '"+enddate+"'";
      var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
      var sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 2, {template: templateSheet}); 
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert("The actions of this function will be irrevocable, please continue if you have verified the data being archived", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.NO){
      return ui.alert("Operation Cancelled")
    } else if (response == ui.Button.YES){
      return sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getDataRange(), {contentsOnly:true});
    } else {
      return ui.alert("Operation has been aborted. If you would like to archive, please try again");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inserting a new sheet on your document by copying it from template sheet:

```js
      var sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 2, {template: templateSheet});
```

so basically all data from the template sheet object is copied to the new sheet.

You should insert it using less options like:

```js
      var sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 2);
```

This will only create a new sheet object, on the index 2.

Here you can see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-sheetindex,-options) about `insertSheet`.

**What is happening with your code?**

Before the `if else` condition the sheet its been already copied, so you feel like it is not working, but it is.

This should do:

```js
function cloneGooglesheet() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var cellfirst = ss.getSheetByName('Master').getRange(4, 1).getValue();
      var celllast = ss.getSheetByName('Master').getRange(10, 1).getValue();
      var startdate = Utilities.formatDate(cellfirst, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");
      var enddate = Utilities.formatDate(celllast, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");

      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert("The actions of this function will be irrevocable, please continue if you have verified the data being archived", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if (response == ui.Button.NO){
      return ui.alert("Operation Cancelled")
    }
    else if (response == ui.Button.YES){
      var sheetName = "Week of '"+startdate+"' to '"+enddate+"'";
      var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 2); 
      templateSheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getDataRange(), {contentsOnly:true});
      return ui.alert("Succesfully archived");      
    } 
    else {
      return ui.alert("Operation has been aborted. If you would like to archive, please try again");
    }
}
```

As you can see I've moved all the sheet insertion and copy lines inside the `else if`, then I've modified it so you first insert a blank spreadsheet and later on you copy the cells you wish from the `templateSheet`